# About minimal prime ideals and varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $W$ be a variety, and $I=\mathbb{I}(M)$, then we have 
$$
I=\operatorname{rad}(I)=P_1\cap\cdots\cap P_n
$$
where $P_i$'s are minimal prime ideals containing $I$.

Thus we have
$$
W=\mathbb{V}(I)=\mathbb{V}(P_1\cap\cdots\cap P_n)\supset\mathbb{V}(P_1)\cup\cdots\cup\mathbb{V}(P_n)
$$

I don't think we can deduce $W=\mathbb{V}(P_1)\cup\cdots\cup\mathbb{V}(P_n)$, but I failed to make an counterexample.

Could anyone make an example for me? Or prove the equality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$V(I \cap J) = V(I \cdot J) = V(I) \cup V(J)$ is a general fact, and easy to prove.

Comment: Got that, thanks...